# Using AJAX with a contact form to remove page reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have seen lots of questions about this on here and have taken the code I have now from several answers.

But for some reason I cant get it to work and I cant figure out why.

I have a HTML form with the code here:

```
<form id="quick_contact" name="quick_contact" action="" method="POST">
    <div class="input-control text">
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter name here">
    </div>
    <div class="space10">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="input-control email">
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" value="" placeholder="Enter email address here"/>
    </div>
    <div class="space10">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="input-control textarea">
        <textarea id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Enter Comments Here"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="space10">&nbsp;</div>
    <button id="quick_submit" name="quick_submit" onclick="quickContact()">Send</button>                      
</form>
```

And I have my jquery here **UPDATED as of Thomas' answer**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function quickContact(){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "quick-contact.php",
        data:
             {
                 name: $('#name').val().trim(),
                 email: $('#email').val().trim(),
                 comments: $('#comments').val().trim(),                 
             },            
        success: function(html) {
                     var submitted = $.trim(html);
                     if (submitted) {
                         alert("Thanks for your submission");
                         $('#quick_contact')[0].reset();
                         return;
                     } else {
                         alert("Failed to submit.");
                         return false;
                }
        }
    });         
};
</script>
```

And here is the PHP which handles the email side of things in a file called "quick-contact.php **again updated as of Thomas' answer**:

```
if(isset($_POST) == true){
    $status = 1 // init to one, assume there will not be an error
    //Store the entered values in the variables
    $name = mysql_escape_string(trim($_POST['name']));
    $email = mysql_escape_string(trim($_POST['email']));
    $comments = mysql_escape_string(trim($_POST['comments']));
    $comments = str_replace('\r\n','<br>',$comments);

    // EMAIL HEADERS
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\n";
    $headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: Normal\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: php\n";          
    $headers .= "From: *****<*****@l*****>\n";

    //SEND EMAIL TO BRANCH
    // EMAIL TITLE
    $subject = $name . " " . get_content(3344);

    //message
    $message1 = "<style type=\"text/css\">";
    $message1 .= "div { font-family: Arial, Verdana, Tahoma; font-size: 10pt; line-height: 120%; }";
    $message1 .= "h1 { margin: 0; font-size: 14pt; }";
    $message1 .= "h2 { margin: 0; font-size: 12pt; }";
    $message1 .= "span { font-size: 9pt; font-weight: bold; }";
    $message1 .= "</style>\n";
    $message1 .= "<div>";
    $message1 .= "<p>" . $name . " " . get_content(3344) . "</p>\n";
    $message1 .= "<p>" . get_content(3345) . "</p>\n";
    $message1 .= "<p><b>" . ucwords(get_content(2869)) . ":</b> " . $name . "<br />";
    $message1 .= "<b>" . ucwords(get_content(27)) . ":</b> " . $email . "<br />";
    $message1 .= "<b>" . ucwords(get_content(1258)) . ":</b> " . $comments . "<br />";
    $message1 .= "</p>\n";
    $message1 .= get_content(893); // King Regards, 
    $message1 .= "<br /><br />";
    $message1 .= "<img src=\"***********\" alt=\"*******\">";
    $message1 .= "<br />";
    $message1 .= "</div>";

    //SEND CUSTOMER AN EMAIL
    // EMAIL TITLE
    $subject2 = get_content(392);

    //message
    $message2 = "<style type=\"text/css\">";
    $message2 .= "div { font-family: Arial, Verdana, Tahoma; font-size: 10pt; line-height: 120%; }";
    $message2 .= "h1 { margin: 0; font-size: 14pt; }";
    $message2 .= "h2 { margin: 0; font-size: 12pt; }";
    $message2 .= "span { font-size: 9pt; font-weight: bold; }";
    $message2 .= "</style>\n";
    $message2 .= "<div>";
    $message2 .= "<p>" . $name . ",</p>\n";
    $message2 .= "<p>" . get_content(392) . "</p>\n";
    $message2 .= "<p>" . str_replace("{TEL_NUMBER}", $header_branch_details[0]['Tel'], str_replace("{BRANCH_EMAIL}", $header_branch_details[0]['SalesEmail'], get_content(2764))) . "</p>\n";
    $message2 .= get_content(893); // King Regards, 
    $message2 .= "<br /><br />";
    $message2 .= "<img src=\"*********\" alt=\"*********\">";
    $message2 .= "<br />";
    $message2 .= "</div>";

    //Send branch email
    $success = mail('***@****.com', $subject, $message1, $headers); 
    //Send customer email
    $success2 = mail($email, $subject2, $message2, $headers);

    if (!$success) {
       $status = 0;
    }   
    echo $status;
}
```

Sorry about the mass of code I really hope someone can help me here

Comment: In your PHP if statement ( if(isset($_POST['quick_submit']) ) you check quick_submit param, but I can't find it in you javascript code. Where is it?

Comment: Shouldn't you make that dataString an object instead of an actual string? The format there is more often used for a GET request. What's the actual problem you have? Any error messages?

Comment: @AlexBor The PHP checks on the submit button and the jquery checks on the submission of the actual form. The javascript should trigger when the form is submitted.

Comment: @iLikeBreakfast I dont really know if dataString is correct over a string but there are no error messages the page just reloads with nothing happened. I tried sticking an alert at the very top of the function(e) above "e.preventDefault();" but It doesnt even do that. However If I stick the alert  here: "$("#quick_contact").submit(alert('hello')function(e){" then it does alert. Again I dont know why

Comment: You don't need to have a "submit" button. Change it to a regular button. I.E. <input type='button' onClick='doSubmission();' />
and then have doSubmission() do the ajax call.

Comment: @ThomasPowers hey, ok I change the submit input to a button and used an onClick event. The alert now shows. But then the page reloads and nothing else happens

Comment: See my answer below. Are you wanting the email to be sent and then the form basically resets itself without a page reload? What exactly are you going for here?

Comment: Open your networktab and see what it gives you. Check the request parameters and the response. ps. You don't need the `form` tag at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the submit type to a button type with an onClick event that calls doSomething().

Then, have doSomething() run the ajax call, like so:

```
function doSomething() {
    $.ajax({
         type: 'post',
         url: 'quick-contact.php',
         data:
         {
             name: $('#name').val().trim(),
             email: $('#email').val().trim(),
             comments: $('#comments').val().trim(),                 
         },
         success: function(html) {
             var status = $.trim(html);
             if (status) {
                 alert("Thanks for your submission");
                 $('#quick_contact')[0].reset();
                 return;
             } else {
                 alert("Failed to submit.");
                 return false;
             }
         }
    });
 }
```

Then in your PHP, all you have to do is check if $_POST isset.

```
 if (($_POST)) {
     $status = 1; // init to one, assume there will not be an error
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     //etc, but FILTER the data coming from the client
 }
```

Also, you may want to do something like this near your mail() function:

```
$success = mail(//etc);
if (!$success) {
   $status = 0;
}

echo $status;
```

If you still have questions, let me know. I'm happy to help.

Comment: Ok I used your answer and now ifI put an alert at the top of the function is does alert. But nothing else happens. My code matches yours but all that happens is the page reloads and thats all. I need the email to be sent and the form reset without a page reload. The page shouldnt reload at any point. I am editing my question to show my current code

Comment: change your:
<input type="submit" id="quick_submit" name="quick_submit" value="Send"> to <input type="button" id="quick_submit" name="quick_submit" value="Send" onClick="quickContact();">

Comment: Sorry That has already been done I forgot to change that in my question.

Comment: Ok. Where are we? What's happening with all of those changes? Does the page still reload? The only way it should reload is if you are calling the submit somewhere. Do you have anything like $('#quick_contact').submit() anywhere? ALSO, your jquery is missing the the if statement on condition if status variable

Comment: I have updated the code in the question with yours now. There is no other call to that jquery function and there is no other function of the same name anywhere else in my code. The page still refreshing on submit with nothing else happening

Comment: Can you email me your code? Something is triggering the submit event. digitalwizard79@gmail.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59738/discussion-between-kevlar-and-thomas-powers).

Comment: Thanks for the chat and your help :) works perfectly now